# Is it possible to overwrite a static JSON file during runtime after getting the updated JSON from a GET request?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My React Native project has a static JSON file from which I access some properties and I am wondering if it is possible to overwrite that JSON during runtime.

Let's say I have a button that makes a GET request for an updated version of that JSON, would it be possible to overwrite that JSON file with the result of my GET request?

I imagine I'd need some sort of React Native filesystem dependency.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a state where you put your JSON data, which get updated every time you make a GET request, which is gonna overite the previous state(data)
Edit : you can use a caching system with RFNS, we have done that in our app and it works perfectly, you just need to know how to use react-native-fs package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, head over to [RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) documentation